# React Native NativeBase Looping Tabs issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

Am using Expo React Native and Native Base library,

While am trying to loop through an array to output Tabs (each user have his own number of tabs)

```
       <Tabs>

        {sectionsTabs.map(section => <Tab
          heading={section.section_name}
          style={{backgroundColor: '#0e0e0e'}}
        >
          <Text>{section_id}</Text>
        </Tab>)}
      </Tabs>
```

SectionsTabs is an array

Below is the error message am getting

[image]

Comment: backgroundColor:-1 will not work

Comment: this is from the nativebase itself, although i checked the source code, couldn't find any -1 value for background.

if i will remove the loop = the code will work fine without issues.